# Python : "unexpected token filenames" for a variable declared the line before

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have this piece of code and for some reason Visual Studio underlies `filename` in `print filename` saying "unexpected token filenames". When I try to compile it throws `invalid syntax`.

```
import os

for filenames in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\output'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print filename
```

How `filename` isn't declared since I declare it the line just before ?

**Full error message :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 1
06, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 8
1, in exec_code
    code_obj = compile(code, file, 'exec')
  File "C:\Users\user\Selenium\stockDataFormater(PY)\stockDataFormater(PY)\stock
DataFormater.py", line 5
    print filename
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3? What’s the full error message?

Comment: yes it's python 3 I've put the full error message in my post

Comment: If you're using python 3 `print` is now a function, so you'd have to write: `print(filename)`.

Comment: The error message shows the real problem. The editor seems to be confused about where the error lies.